# How to get this value inside RETURN

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm doing something new & unexpected tonight with a lot of errors, and I have asked a lot of stupid questions tonight, so I promise this is the last one :)

In last post, I received an answer that I can list all taxonomy terms in a list with following code:

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_terms('YOUR-TAXONOMY');
    if ( $terms ) :
?>
<ul id="portfolioFilter">
    <li class="filter" data-filter="all">All</li>
    <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ): ?>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But how can I use this code in the plugin that  I'm currently working, which looks like:

```
return 
'<div class="listings clearfix">' 
. '<li class="filter" data-filter="'. $term->slug .'>'. esc_html($term->name) .'</li>'
. '<div class="inner-div preview-wrap">'
. '<div id="portfolio-wrap">'
. '<div id="portfolio_thumbs" class="columns-3">'
. '<ul id="grid" class="sortablePortfolio clearfix">'
. $list 
. '</ul>'
. '</div>'
. '</div>'
. '</div>'.
```

Third line of the above code is the place where I want the list to appear. I did a lot of things, but WordPress is just returning some errors. Is it possible to run this code inside it.

It's last question, and it will complete my first project, so please help :)

Thanks!

Comment: You need a semi-colon at the end. This looks like a PHP error to me. Can you explain what is WordPress about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a PHP question then a WordPress one but the answer is simple, just use PHP's output buffer by wrapping the first code snippet eg:

//create a function for the filters

```
function get_filters(){
    $terms = get_terms('YOUR-TAXONOMY');
    if ( $terms ) {
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <ul id="portfolioFilter">
            <li class="filter" data-filter="all">All</li>
            <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ): ?>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return false;
}
```

//and then call that function in your second snippet:

```
return 
'<div class="listings clearfix">' 
. '<li class="filter" data-filter="'. $term->slug .'>'. esc_html($term->name) .'</li>'
. '<div class="inner-div preview-wrap">'
. '<div id="portfolio-wrap">'
. '<div id="portfolio_thumbs" class="columns-3">'
. '<ul id="grid" class="sortablePortfolio clearfix">'
. get_filters() 
. '</ul>'
. '</div>'
. '</div>'
. '</div>';
```